# Install windows store app for all users

Tags: windows-8, certificate, visual-studio

I have a Windows Store App project from Visual Studio, and I'd like to install it for all users. I don't need to put it on the app store or anything, I only want to distribute it locally to other users on the computer.

I have found [this link](http://www.verboon.info/2012/02/managing-windows-8-metro-style-apps-with-dism/) and [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/02/12/create-a-windows-store-appx-package-and-sign-it.aspx), which tell me how to install an `appx` for all users and how to create an `appx` from a bundle created by Visual Studio.

Is there a way to do this without needing to create a certificate? Or if it is not possible, to explain what exactly is going on with these certificates?

Comment: Universal Windows Applications only support Windows 10.  So this about Windows 8 or Windows 10?  Windows Store applications are required to be signed, it also is not free to publish to the store, the certificate which is issue to you by Microsoft is required so what you do publish is signed.

Comment: I don't need to put it on the store, I am only looking for deploying the apps I make to the other users on the computer.

Comment: You asked what the certificate was for.  I provided the answer to that question.  In other words my comment was indicating there isn't a way to do this without creating a certificate.  Of course if you clarify your question I will also provide an answer.

Comment: @Ramhound so I don't need to use the certificate to run an app locally? And I am indeed not building an UWP app, but a windows store app.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid the store then you need to "sideload" the apps onto the machines.

MS offers all the info you need for that. ie:

- [Sideload LOB apps in Windows 10](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt269549(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Try it out: sideload Windows Store apps](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/jj874388.aspx).

You will still need a [certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate) to sign the code, but it can be [self-signed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate) (in which case you'll have to provide and install the certificates to the clients).

Signing the code is required to run them to prove that the app is trusted. It does this by specifying a chain of trust and authority, and by using mechanisms to prove that code hasn't been altered from its original state.

More information about code signing in general is available [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing).

Blurb:

> The most common use of code signing is to provide security when deploying; in some programming languages, it can also be used to help prevent namespace conflicts. Almost every code signing implementation will provide some sort of digital signature mechanism to verify the identity of the author or build system, and a checksum to verify that the object has not been modified.